# _Essential Algorithms_ O(n) answer doesn't make sense?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

It's from Essentials Algorithms by Rod Stephens.

Assume we have 2 algorithms that solve the same task in 1500N and 30N*N, what the algorithm and when would we prefer to use?

And the answer is that we'd prefer to use the 1500N algorithm if N is lower or equal than 50, and the 30N*N algorithm when N is greater than 50.

So, the question is why would we use them like this? Suppose N is 2, then 1500N will be slower than 30N*N because 3000 is larger than 120, thus the second algorithm is faster when N is lower than 50. What have I been missing here? Doesn't it mean that the answer in the book is wrong?

Comment: It’s the other way around and the question likely wants to illustrate that constants matter. The first algorithm is O(N) with a constant c = 1500, and the second is O(N^2) with a constant c = 40. You’d say that the first algorithm is better and you’d be right but only in the general case when you take into account large inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it seems that the answer has the alternatives swapped. The *O(n*n)* algorithm will be faster when *n* is below 50. The *O(n)* algorithm should be preferred if the value is larger than 50, or if you cannot predict the value of *n*. The general observation is that lower values of the big-oh exponent will scale better as *n* increases.

The [Errata page for the book](https://www.wiley.com/en-fi/Essential+Algorithms:+A+Practical+Approach+to+Computer+Algorithms-p-9781118612101) already notes this mistake (Appendix B, p 488).